# Mutual SSL for SOAP client using Mule ESB

Tags: java, web-services, soap, mule

I am brand new to Mule and am trying to figure out how to put together a flow that makes a SOAP-XML request over HTTPS when a certificate must be presented to the server to create the SSL connection. (This service provider requires mutual SSL for authentication.)

I searched for information on this particular kind of integration and didn't find anything that involved a client side certificate. Any pointers would be appreciated.